# Solving $f''(t) =k(t) f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can one indicate the general method to solve the differential equation

$$ f''(t) = k(t) f(t) $$

where $k : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function ?

Thanks !

Comment: Put $u=f'$ and $v=f$. Then the equation becomes $$\begin{align}u'&=0u+kv\\v'&=u+0v\end{align}$$ and solve the linear system $X'=AX$ you get.

Comment: Aas far as I know there is no such general method.

Comment: @Alamos - that should be an answer.